# Using gfortran with libraries

Tags: makefile, libraries, legacy-code, gfortran

I have a legacy code written using fortran 77.  I'm trying to build it with gfortran.  But I seem to be failing at the stage where I include the libraries in the build.  The dozens of *.f source files compile fine, but when they are being linked, I get a bunch of "undefined reference" errors all relating to subroutines and functions that are defined in my libraries.  I already ran the makefile for the libraries first, so the variables I need should all be exported.  I'm playing with the "-L" option, but can't get it to work as desired.

First, here's my syntax of the linking line in my makefile:

```
 29 $(PROGRAM): $(SRCS) $(LIBS)
 30         $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $+ -L$(DIRLIB)
```

PROGRAM is the program name, SRCS are all the compiled source files, LIBS is set to two different files - an archive file (file.a) and a file.o file.
FC is gfortran, I don't have any specific linking flags for FLFLAGS as of now, and DIRLIB is the main directory of the libraries.
The thing is that my *.o files that resulted from building my librarires don't reside in just the main directory, DIRLIB.  DIRLIB contains several directories, all with their own *.o files that are needed by my code.

I tried adding each individual directory after the -L option (e.g. DIRLIB/DIR1/*.o DIRLIB/DIR2/*.o DIRLIB/DIR3/*.o), but I eventually start getting errors that some subroutines are multiply defined.
All this business of user-defined libraries and archive files just confuses me and I'm pretty new to making makefiles in the first place, so I'm just taking a shot in the dark here that somebody might be able to help me shed some light on this.

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but have you tried the *readelf -a* command on any of the *\*.o* files?  The *readelf* will at least tell you what symbols, if any, the linker is trying to find.  This might afford you a clue as to what to try next.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries need to come after the `.o` files that reference them in the linking command.
I'm guessing the object file in `LIBS` comes after the library, but needs some of the procedures from it. Can you show the command that is actually run (with all variables expanded), to confirm this?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to this, but I got side-tracked with other work.  I learned that the overall process is to compile the source files that are in the library, then include the .o files in a .a file, which is what you should include in the linking stage.  Unfortunately, I just couldn't get this to work, so I simply took the library source files and just built them right along with the main program source files and linked them all at once... no use of the -L option or messing with static libraries required.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build this code again using the library.  It worked this time.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing the same thing in my makefile as I did before, so it must be related to the library I had.  Maybe somebody altered it along the way and inadvertently broke it.  But I got a fresh clean copy of the library.  My steps are to:

1) run the makefile for the library source files; it creates a library.a archive file

2) run my code makefile:

- it has a line to specify the location of this archive file and assign it to "DIRLIB"

  DIRLIB := ../library
- then the linking command of the makefile becomes

  $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $+ -L$(DIRLIB) -lskit

FC is my compiler, FLFLAGS are my linking flags, -L is the option specifying the location of libraries to be included and -lskit is a crucial option which appears to allow the use of F77 libraries... without the -lskit option, I get many undefined reference errors.  It may have been that last time I was not including this -lskit option at the end.